# simple way to change JavaFX treeview background and text color

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

This seems like something crazy simple, I'm new with JavaFX, and I cannot change the background and text color of JavaFX TreeView (added inside of a GridPane). Ive initialized the treeview constructor with the root node of populated treeitem.

in the .css:

```
.myTree {
   -fx-font: 12px Tahoma;
   -fx-stroke: #eeeeee;
   -fx-background-color: #0a0a0a;
   -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
   }
```

and in the code

```
 treeView.getStyleClass().add("myTree");
```

the font sets, but nothing else. I cant seem to find any example of anyone changing the background of treeview - lots of doing fancy changes on select and hover.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the background color on the cells:

```
.myTree .tree-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #0a0a0a ;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff ;
}
```

Comment: aaaah! thanks, that does the trick, I didnt know about the tree-cell tag, that openned up a lot of other good things !

Comment: The cells are opaque by default, so even though you changed the background of the `TreeView`, you can't see through the cells to it.

Comment: lead me to a bunch of good stuff like :                                                   .myTree .tree-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #cccccc;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    -fx-border-color: #ff0000;
}

Comment: See the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#treecell), if you haven't already. Be sure to also pay attention to the "Also inherits properties from ..." sections.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple way to get away from the yucky white tree background color, you can do this in the ***scene builder***.

1. Place a "region" over the tree view.  This will resize correctly.
2. Make sure the region is on top (send to front).
3. Set the regions's color. (a dark color, i.e. blue).
   i. Use  -fx-background-color : darkblue
4. Set opacity to about 0.15
5. Set mouseTransparency to true.
6. Done!